# using pandas, trying to get to a .describe in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-lab

```
cols = ['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']
for v in cols:
    autos[cols].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()
```

dataset = autos.

want to do on each of the three columns:

```
{.value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()}
```

edit; solution compiled from multiple people

```
cols = ['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']
for v in cols:
    temp = autos[v].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()
    print(temp)
```

alternate solution

```
cols = ['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']
[print (autos[v].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()) for v in cols]
```

needed to change to autos[v] to make use of the for loop, and set to a variable to easily print the out the result of each loop.

thanks all.

Comment: can you do it in two lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: in your for loop, do autos[cols].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False) then do autos[cols].describe()

Comment: still gives the same "  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts' "

Comment: change your for loop.  Use: for col in autos.columns: autos[cols].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False)

Comment: {for cols in autos.columns: 
    autos[cols].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()}  doesn't return any info, not sure why.

Comment: So it worked? I  left out the describe to make sure for loop worked.

Comment: got help from the dataquest forums as well, needed to put in||| cols = ['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']
for v in cols:
    temp = autos[v].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()
    print(temp) |||  didn't have the print function, and didn't call for v after autos. so yeah, the combination of the two fixes solved my problem.

Comment: Nice. I’ll just mention that if we started off with you providing the original data and the error message you received this would have been easier. My fault for not mentioning it. Sorry!

Comment: Also if you like the answer below. Give him a +1 if you can. It helps a lot. It’s a reward for us.

Comment: thanks. will make sure i do now and in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cols = ['date_crawled', 'ad_created', 'last_seen']
[print (autos[v].value_counts(normalize=True, dropna=False).describe()) for v in cols]
```

Does this work for you?